# 3 phase sine inverter

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, sine

i am trying to control bldc motor (sinusoidal commutation). I am somewhat controlling bldc motor, by applying sinusoidal voltage with 120 phase shifted to the phases.

Now my issues is i cant able to vary the speed, i runs at the max speed.

- At a maximum speed, For 120 phase shifted it sucks around 2 amp but for 130 phase shift it sucks only 1 amp. Why so?
- Then bu noticing the phase to phase waveform, the output phase to phase is not good. But phase to gnd is probably good.

Here are the waveforms....

**Phase 130 degree shifted**
[image]
**Phase 120 shifted**
[image]
**phase to phase**
[image]
**Phase to gnd**
[image]

Why phase to phase is looking so horrible i don't know. Guide me frds where i am wrong.....

Comment: Friends guide me , why my phase to phase waveform is like this. Why i cant able to control the speed.

Comment: Guys not even a single reply... I am just eager to learn and develop skills, thought they are many professionals will help for the people who seeks to get or learn new thinks. Actually I am really losing my hope to learn new thinks. But i will never quit for sure. Thank you